# Is iPhone app name and Application name in app store should be same?

Tags: iphone

i am created one app, when i upload app store, raised one doubt, Whether app name what i given while developing and app store app name should be same or different?

Regards
Srini

Answer (score 4):

Apple's specific guideline as of this moment:

> App names in iTunes Connect and as displayed on a device should be similar, so as not to cause confusion

The name you were using while you were developing it isn't important, necessarily -- you can completely change the name of the app before submitting.

It's just important that the name you used when you submitted the app for approval is similar to the name under the icon. From my experience, it's fine to do the following with the name under the icon:

- Eliminate articles: "The Best Game" becomes "Best Game"
- Use initials if the name is very long: "Greatest Calculator Built By Man" becomes "GCBBM"

The key, I suspect, is that when the user sees the app on the phone they'll be able to recognize it based on the name of the app they saw when they bought it.

Answer (score 0):

Many apps have significantly different Bundle Display Names, product file names, and the Application Names in their iTunes descriptions.  For instance, short display names under the icon, long app store names with spaces and special characters, medium length file/ipa names with no spaces or special characters.  Etc.

However, if the names are misleadingly different, Apple may find a problem with accepting the app.